# powershell variable syntax $($a)?

Tags: powershell

I have a simple question regarding why something works the way it does and I cant seem to readily find out why.
I was trying to run the following command:

`foreach($a in $list){set-mailboxcalendarpermissions -identity $($a):\calendar`

while it works just fine, I don't know what adding the `$(   )` actually does.
When I do `($a):\calendar` it would return `(variable):\calendar` with the parenthesis, but adding the extra "$" fixes it.  why?

Thank you all for your help with this terribly worded question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$()` is a [subexpression operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx).  It means "evaluate this first, and do it separately as an independent statement".

Most often, its used when you're using an inline string.  Say:

```
$x = Get-ChildItem C:\;
$x | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "The file is $($_.FullName)";
}
```

Compare that to:

```
$x = Get-ChildItem C:\;
$x | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "The file is $_.FullName";
}
```

You can also do things like `$($x + $y).ToString()`, or `$(Get-Date).AddDays(10)`.

Here, without the subexpression, you'd get `$a:\calendar`.  Well, the problem there is that the colon  after a variable is an operator.  Specifically, [the scope operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx).  To keep PowerShell from thinking you're trying to look for a variable in the `a` namespace, the author put the variable in a subexpression.

As far as I've been able to tell using PS for the past few years, parentheses without the dollar sign are also essentially subexpressions.  They won't be evaluated as a subexpression when within a string, but otherwise they usually will.  It's kind of a frustrating quirk that there's no clear difference.

Comment: You could also mention that a simpler way to prevent the colon being interpreted as a namespace separator would have been to write `${a}:\calendar`

Comment: BTW, the main difference between `(pipeline)` and `$(statement-list)` is that the `$()` contains a statement-list which includes `if`, `while` etc. as well as a pipeline, but parentheses need a pipeline, i.e. an assignment, expression, or command. Also in strings only `$()` has meaning.

Answer (score 10):

The `$()` is the subexpression operator. It causes the contained expressions to be evaluated and it returns all expressions as an array (if there is more than one) or as a scalar (single value). Plain parentheses `()` are simply the mathematical precedence operator and therefore just work in arithmetic expressions to give precedence

Notably, `$()` is interpreted within a string, whereas `()` will be just be taken literally - it has no special meaning. So the following:

```
$a = "Hello"
"$($a.Length)"
```

gives

```
5
```

whereas

```
"($a.Length)"
```

gives

```
"(Hello.Length)"
```

As I said, the `$()` can consist of multiple expressions, all of which are returned as output. `()` does not do this. So this is an error as the contents are not an arithmetic expression:

```
(1;2)
```

whereas this

```
$(1;2)
```

evaluates to an array and outputs:

```
1
2
```

The expression $($a) is evaluated before the application of the trailing scope `:` operator and prevents the scope being applied directly to `a`, instead `$a` is evaluated first and then the scope is applied.