# How to fix "docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments

Tags: docker, docker-exec

I'm trying to login into container using following command.

`docker exec -t -i $(docker container ps -f "name=mycontainer" -q) sh`

It works well in Ubuntu and isn't working in Windows 10.

Comment: You have to explicitly specify that Windows is host. In Windows there is no `$(...)` function, so you need to get your container name in other ways. Why not simply write `mycontainer` ?

Comment: @grapes in cmd you are correct, but powershell supports it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984637/powershell-variable-syntax-a

Comment: @secustor good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On my windows machine, it only works when I supply the **/bin/bash** to the command.

Here is the working command:

```
docker exec -it mongodb /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `"` to work.

`docker exec -ti $(docker container ps -f name=mycontainername -q) sh`

But why would you this anyway? 
You can run:
`docker exec -ti mycontainername sh`